# Link on flash object does not work in Google Chrome or IE

Tags: flash, google-chrome, hyperlink, anchor, rollover

The basic problem I have encountered is that my flash video is linked to another page and for some reason the link does not respond in Chrome or Internet Explorer. It works fine in firefox and safari. You can even see the url it is supposed to link toward at the bottom of the page when you hover over it. Even more strange is that apparently if you right click on the link in Chrome and then immediately left click without moving the mouse, the links seem to work in Chrome.

The flash object itself is a movie, with an action to play on rollover. I have read forums that advised an Onload approach within the object itself rather than an anchor outside of the object, in addition to adding actions to the flash object, but neither approach has been respected by Chrome. So it seems like its less an issue of where the anchor is and more something to do specifically with Chromes ability to find a focus point to click on the link. Just a though. Appreciate any feedback you guys can give me as I have searched through tons of forums and I have not found a single answer.

Below is the website url, if you try to click the links in Chrome the issue is apparent.

http://www.heatherdenny.com/

Comment: An image showing your problem is much better than a link to an external website. Questions and answers here are supposed to continue exist and be useful even if external websites go down or the problem is fixed on your end.

Comment: Regardless of this issue, I'd suggest to add a transparent button covering the area where the links bounce so that the mouse cursor gets a chance to switch to a hand shape to suggest a clickable item... are those titles mouse enabled?

Comment: Luis the titles are mouse enabled, if you hold the cursor over them for a little while you can see the hand shape appears. In terms of a transparent button are you referring to an additional flash object on top of the link?

Comment: Emil, I completely understand the stand alone idea so its helpful in the future, but this is a hard issue to depict with any image as you cant show the inability for something to happen. Also, Im sure the description combined with any feedback should hopefully lead people in the correct direction. If you know of a way to upload something stand alone, feel free to let me know and Ill do what I can.

Comment: @ylair yes, that's what I meant. When I tried your page on Chrome, the hand shape showed up very briefly and quickly went away, which made me wonder if whatever has the link is covered by something not mouse enabled.

Comment: @Luis I gave it a shot, unfortunately, adding a transparent layer over the top blocks the rollover that activates the movie. However the link does work. Any thoughts?

Comment: @ylair true, that would be a consequence... I think I'd look into triggering the rollover from the transparent objects layered over the titles

Comment: @Luis That is what I was thinking, but I not sure what actions to use to accomplish that. When I add an additional action to the getURL in the transparent layer, the getURL seems to override it and ignore it. If you have specific code in mind feel free to add it. 
Thanks.

Comment: @Luis It just occurred to me that I was adding it to the same state, if I add the rollover play to the "over" state and leave the geturl in the "Click" state on the button then it might work. Correct?